# powershell script statement to fetch a particular file path

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have the following statement in PowerShell script that fetches a particular file

```
$imptext = "E:\imp\old"

 $strAttachment = dir $imptext | sort -prop  LastWriteTime | Where-Object {$_.name -like "*Imptextfiles*"} | Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)} | select -last 1 | foreach-object -process { $_.FullName }
```

How can I write to host the path of that file `$strAttachment` along with the exact file name?

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the directory of the file? Just use the [Split-Path cmdlet:](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113404)

```
$attachmentDirectory = Split-Path $strAttachment
```

You could also use `Get-DirectoryName`:

```
$attachmentDirectory =[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($strAttachment)
```

Also, you can improve your inital script (using `-Filter` instead of two `Where-Object`)

```
$strAttachment = Get-ChildItem $imptext -Filter '*Imptextfiles*' | 
    Where-Object Lastwritetime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-1) | 
    sort LastWriteTime | 
    select -last 1 | 
    select -ExpandProperty FullName
```